# PHP function return value disappears (?)

Tags: php, function, return-value

In the following function call the log files show me that 
even though before the return call the variable has a value the variable receiving the return value is empty

the if empty has just been included because I didn't believe what is happening.

What am I missing? Any clou?

```
    ...
    ...
    $workingProductArray=$this->placeNextItem($workingProductArray, ... );

    if (empty($workingProductArray)){
        write_log ("DYING array empty");
        die(); //<-- and indeed the system dies.
    }
}

private function placeNextItem(array $workingProductArray, ... )
{

    if ($this->areAllProductsIgnored($workingProductArray)){

        print_r($workingProductArray); // <-- SHOWS EXPECTED ARRAY AND VALUES
        return $workingProductArray; // returning this value
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just digging into the code. and I just noticed I made a terrible thinking mistake...
(which you can't see on the mentioned code... here the code to the function's end)

```
...
...
$workingProductArray=$this->placeNextItem($workingProductArray, ... );

if (empty($workingProductArray)){
    write_log ("DYING array empty");
    die(); //<-- and indeed the system dies.
}
}

private function placeNextItem(array $workingProductArray, ... ){

if ($this->areAllProductsIgnored($workingProductArray)){

    print_r($workingProductArray); // <-- SHOWS EXPECTED ARRAY AND VALUES
    return $workingProductArray; // returning this value
}
...
$this->placeNextItem(array $workingProductArray, ...);
}
```

So I call this function also from within (recursively), I thought the return statement would go to the method above but instead it goes (doh! off course!) back to it's recursive caller, which is the same method where I have to return the value too...

easy fix:

```
private function placeNextItem(array $workingProductArray, ... ){

if ($this->areAllProductsIgnored($workingProductArray)){

    print_r($workingProductArray); // <-- SHOWS EXPECTED ARRAY AND VALUES
    return $workingProductArray; // returning this value
}
...
return $this->placeNextItem(array $workingProductArray, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird! Try to not `print_r2` from placeNextItem function if still doesn't work try to name `$workingProductArray` to something else for placeNextItem.

Comment: thanks i was just digging into the code. and I just noticed I made a terrible thinking mistake...
I call this frunction also from within (recursively), so apparently I thought the return statement would go to the method above but it goes back to it's recursive caller from within...